# Scala - Build AST Parser - How to return a List of a predifined class?

Tags: java, scala, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm doing my homework which requires me to build an `Abstract Syntax Tree Parser` for a "new" program language, **using `Scala`**. And this is the code that I'm having trouble at:

```
case class ParamDecl(val id: Id, val paramType: Type) extends Decl {
        override def toString = "param(" + id + "," + paramType + ")"
}
// myIdent: a valid identifier
def myIdent: Parser[Id] = ident ^^ {case i => Id(i)}

// myIdentList: a list of myIdent, seperated by comma(s)
def myIdentList: Parser[List[Id]] = rep1sep( myIdent, "," )

// paramList: a list of params, declared by case class ParamDecl above
def paramsList: Parser[List[ParamDecl]] = repsep((myIdentList <~ ":") ~ varType, ";") ^^ {
      case List() => List()
      // TODO my problem
      // how to return a list of ParamDecl ?
      // each ParamDecl should follow its nearby ParamDecl by using ":::"
}
```

What I want to do now is that the `paramList` Parser will recognize the input list of parameters and return a List of `ParamDecl`, separated by the `:::` sign.

The below code is what I've just tried and I think it logically solve the problem, but I got an error:

```
def paramsList: Parser[List[ParamDecl]] = repsep((myIdentList <~ ":") ~ varType, ";") ^^ {
      case List() => List()
      case paramDeclList => paramDeclList.tail.foldLeft(paramDeclList.head)((a,b) => a match { // this line throw an error says that: "type mismatch, found: [List[Id], Type]" required: List[ParamDecl]
        case x ~ y => List(x.map(ParamDecl(_, y)):::b)
      })
    }
```

I hope you guys can help me with this. I'm getting used to Scala so maybe I will make a lot of mistakes. Thanks so much in advanced !

Answer (score 0):

The accumulator comes first in the arguments to the folder function you pass to `foldLeft` - it should be `(b, a)` not `(a, b)`. In general I'd suggest using more meaningful names.

Also, why are you using `paramDeclList.head` as the base case of your fold? You don't need the separate cases either. Just start with an empty `List[ParamDecl]`:

```
def paramsList: Parser[List[ParamDecl]] = repsep((myIdentList <~ ":") ~ varType, ";") ^^ {
  paramDeclList => paramDeclList.foldLeft(List[ParamDecl]())(
    (alreadyParsed,next) => next match {
    case x ~ y => List(x.map(ParamDecl(_, y)):::alreadyParsed)
  })
}
```